# Does Hadoop have multiple local temporary file locations prior to data being placed in the datanodes?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hadoop2

I think i understand the basics of the Hadoop architecture and stucture.

I am wondering, does all data going into a Hadoop cluster have to pass through the same local temporary file location?

I get that prior to data being written to a datanode it is cached in a local temporary file location. Is this a single file location per namenode where all data going into the cluster (from possibly more than one upload) is stored, prior to the namenode assigning which datanode for it to be stored in? or can Hadoop even handle multiple simultaenous uploads from different locations (say multiple computers uploading different large files to a Cloud based Hadoop cluster)

Please help i cant find this information anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understood this correctly. The name node never receives any data that's sent to hdfs. All it does is allocate blocks on data nodes, thus communicating with meta data only. The protocol goes roughly like this (don't know the details but you'll get the picture):

1. Client requests a block of the certain size from the name node. The block may have to be replicated across mutiple machines.
2. Name node selects one data node where it will allocate space for the block, and sends request to it.
3. Data node allocates the space on it's machine for the block and sends back the reply.
4. If name node receives the reply, it sends the responce back to client, giving it the ip address and id of the block on the data node.
5. Client then contacts the data node and initiates data transfer with it. It is implementation detail whether the data is written directly to disk or stays in memory for a while, but it remains on the data node only.
6. If replication is needed, data node repeats what client has done and distributes the block to other data nodes.
7. Finally, name node is notified and transaction commits.

Read [hadoop architecture book](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html) on hadoop website for details.

Comment: I think i understand this better now, thank you very much! 

It was the stage 5 you say above that had me confused. I was unsure the technique Hadoop used to deal with the data in a temporary manner, i.e. whether it was written directly to storage blocks, held in memory (and where this memory allocation was), and what effect an error (e.g. power failure/network interruption) would have vis-a-vis the incomplete data block.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that if a failure happens during the transaction, you'll get an exception on the client side, and HDFS will roll back changes. Exception to this is if a data node failure happens after a suffice number of good replicas have been written. Otherwise, when your file close operation returns you can rest assured that your data has been written to disk and with the configured number of replicas as well.